# Java MVC, what model to use for add screens?

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller

I have a class called Member which I use as the model for one of my views. This view allows the user to view and edit details of a particular Member. My question is what model should I use for a different view that allows the user to add new members? Should I use the existing Member class and adapt it for this use, or should I create a new model class dedicated to adding new Members, and if so what should it be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, you have a class Member which does, contrary to what one might expect reading the class name, not represent a single `Member` but rather a `MemberModel`. This could be a mere naming issue.

Suppose your class `Member` has the capability to add, edit and grant access to particular members (directly or indirectly), it would  make sense to adapt your existing model class so that it supports adding new members- for example by adding a method `addMember()` which can be called by the corresponding views.

It is fine to manage the functionality of accessing, editing and adding members via a single model. The model provides methods to your views which enables them to access, edit and add members and makes it possible for views to listen to changes of the model they are interested in (e.g. via listeners).

Depending on factors like the complexity of your project it could in principle make sense  to divide your model into submodels, so that your model will be a composition of submodels (represented by individual classes). However, the role of serving as an interface to the functionality of accessing and editing members and the functionality of adding members should be fulfilled by the same class in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

What i can understand is that you have a class Member which is a model. If you want to use a model to add a member, exposing it in top layers like controller is not appreciated. What you can do is to have a Criteria class or [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). These classes could carry all the data that is required from the top level to DAO layer.

If this is not what you are expecting, can you elaborate more on your query.

Answer (score 1):

On MVC you normaly use the same model for all the actions that depends on that model. So if you have a member model, it'll be used to create, read, update and delete The famous four operations that are called **CRUD**.

So yes, the best option is to use the same class, once it will do the conection with the DAO layer of your project. You can fill a member object with information and send it foward to the DAO class that will register it on your dataBase, and then the DataBase can return it empty again for the next use, or don't even return it at all since you probably won't be needing it anymore. It's simple and easy to use.

Some tip about how to best manage the Adding, Editing and Deleting.

Your best option is:

- Create a screen that show the user all members and one "New", "Edit" and "Delete" button, on which the New creates a new Member, the Edit edits the selected member, and the delete deletes the selected member.

For this you can create three views (not recommended) or just one, since member will always have the same fields (right? something like "name", "id"...). But one that requires operation as parameter. So you can do something like this:

```
 try {
                View frame = new frame("add");
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And change "add" to "edit" or "delete" as requisitation. And on the frame called, you can just configure it to as the operation requires.